# xamarin.social missing and cannot be installed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.social

I am trying to run /xamarin-forms-samples/EmployeeDirectory in xamarin studio on my Mac.

I did not find xamarin.social in the packages and I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Social' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Xamarin'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234)
>   (EmployeeDirectory.iOS)

Trying to install xamarin.social I get the error:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Social 1.1.7'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

What to do?
Thank you

Comment: That is an "old" component, it only has `monotouch` and `monoandroid` targets, I would just grab the source and update/use what you need out of it : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Social

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks, I moved one step ahead.  Now how can I access the employee directory data? Where are they stored?